# Should we help seedlings recover from a bent shape?

Tags: peppers, chili, seedlings, technique

Young seedlings are susceptible to bending caused by external force such as heavy wind or flood. The seedlings just lie on the soil and cannot lift up by itself.

Should we help them?

I have been growing a pepper chilli. It was bent to the ground because of lack of support. I forgot to help it recover (usually with a stick and a string to tie them). It continued to grow and grow straight up from the bending point, in a 90 degree turn. The bending point was hardened and I don't think that it is hurting the plant.

Answer (score 6):

If the leaves/cotyledons are lying on the soil I would attempt to do something about this, so they would not rot. If it is only a part of the stem – don't bother. The seedling will continue growing up. When transplanting just plant it deeper, to put the bending point underground. It will become a part of the root system – not even hurting the appearance of the plant.